# Prove stationarity

Tags: time-series, self-study, expected-value, covariance

It can be easy question, but it is a part of bigger exercise. I have problem with lack of statement "uncorrelated"

Prove that if ${X_t,t \in T}$ is stationary, then $Y_t = X_t - X_{t-1}$ is also stationary.

I don't know what to do with step with $E[|X_t X_{t-1}|]$ and with $Cov(X_{t+h},X_{t})-Cov(X_{t+h},X_{t-d})-Cov(X_{t+h-d},X_{t})+Cov(X_{t+h-d},X_{t-d})$

Comment: Stationarity doesn't mean uncorrelated.

Comment: This question requires the self-study tag.